# knockout.js input box event change - passes old value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

When adding a change event binding to an input box using knockout.js the old value is passed to the change function when the event is fired. I can work around this by using blur. Is this the intended behavior? Is the idea to use the change event to have the old value and then use a normal selector to get the value from the dom? It seems counter intuitive.

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8KE7G/)

```
JavaScript
----------
var data = {
    saved_value:"1",
    value_changed: function(data){
        alert(data.saved_value());
    }
};
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

HTML
----
Current Value:<span data-bind="text:saved_value"></span><br/>
<input data-bind="event:{change:value_changed},value:saved_value"></input>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the text and value bindings:

```
Current Value:<span data-bind="text: saved_value"></span><br/>
<input data-bind="value: saved_value"></input>
```

And change the JavaScript to this:

```
var data = {
    saved_value: "1"    
};

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);​
```

Here's an associated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6zmJs/

If you want to `alert()` the value of `saved_value` when it is updated you could use `ko.computed` or `viewModel.saved_value.subscribe(function(value) { alert(value); });` -- although those aren't the only ways to do this.

Comment: saved_value should be ko.observable("1")

Answer (score 82):

Update: For newer versions of knockout, you can replace the value binding with [textInput](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html), which handles many edge cases not covered by `valueUpdate`.

---

No, this is not the right way to do things.

You're getting the old value because saved_value doesn't get updated until the textbox loses focus.

If you want to push the new value in as the user types, using the valueUpdate option of the input binding:

```
<input data-bind="event: { change: value_changed }, value: saved_value, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
```

The valueUpdate option takes an event name (e.g. 'keyup'). When that event fires, your saved_value will be updated.

---

**Now let me propose an alternate solution.**

Still do the valueUpdate binding like I showed above, but instead of listening for the changed event, just subscribe to the observable:

```
<input data-bind="textInput: saved_value" />
```

Then in JS:

```
var viewModel = {
    saved_value: ko.observable("1"),
};
viewModel.saved_value.subscribe(function (newValue) {
   alert(data.saved_value());
});
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: I have to use 'afterkeydown', otherwise I'm one character late.

Comment: Is there a reason why not using the `textInput binding`? 

The documentation of KO recommends to use the `textInput binding` instead of the `value binding`: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html

"Although the value binding can also perform two-way binding between text boxes and viewmodel properties, you should prefer textInput whenever you want immediate live updates."

Comment: Yes. The reason is that this answer was written before textinput binding existed.

Comment: Updated the answer to use the new textInput binding.

Comment: the alternative solution was exactly what I was looking for when I needed a proper "text input changed" event handler.

Comment: @JudahHimango I almost used your solution in a much newer version of Knockout, so I figured it was worth mentioning the textInput binding.

Answer (score 13):

If you put the 'event' option at the end you don't need the 'valueUpdate' option.
Like this:

`<input data-bind="value: saved_value, event: { change: value_changed }" />`

Also note that when you make use of subscribe to an observable, it gets triggered every time your value changes. (either by user interaction or programmatically).

Comment: So the order in which items are in "data-bind" has relevance? Is there document somewhere that explains what rules should be followed so that I might avoid future gotchas?

Comment: Yes, the order matters, they happen in order from left to right (depending somewhat on their functionality)

Comment: Just throwing this out there, but if you're using the "checked" binding, using event at the end *does not* make it wait until the data has changed. It will still use the old value.

Comment: As of knockout v3.4.0, this is incorrect. Perhaps it was a bug?

Answer (score 3):

Try this in the data bind write event handlers, after the value handlers and not before:

```
<input data-bind="value: property, event:{ change: doSomething}" />
```

Comment: This was exactly my issue.  Thank you!

Comment: How is this different from [Fraggy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9637243/712526)?