# Call function on input change with knockout.js (valueUpdate)

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0, knockout-3.2

I'm trying to call a function when my input value gets updated. 
The function will validate the input value and set a flag to true or false which will be used in multiple elements in the DOM.

I have been trying the proposed solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9543995/1081396):

```
<input data-bind="event: { change: value_changed }, value: saved_value, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
```

But it doesn't seem to work on afterKeyDown. It only calls the function on unfocus as you can see here:
http://jsfiddle.net/imac/hY5T2/142/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try this instead http://jsfiddle.net/hY5T2/145/ . cheers

Comment: valueUpdate just updates the observable when the key is pressed (as specified in your code). You can try subscribing the observable and check the necessary logic there.

Comment: most imp thing although your observable gets updated after `afterkeydown` but `change` works differently which fires only when focus is lost .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an update of your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hY5T2/144/)

```
<input data-bind="value: demo, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />


var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.demo = ko.observable('');
    self.myFunction = function(){
        alert("fired");
    }
}

var VM = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(VM);

VM.demo.subscribe(function(){
    VM.myFunction();
});
```

I hope this is what you wanted??

Thanks

EDIT:

Without subscriber. [JSFiddle without subscriber](https://jsfiddle.net/hY5T2/146/)

```
var viewModel = function () {

    var self = this;

    self.demo = ko.observable('');

    self.myFunction = function () {
        alert("fired");
    }

    self.worker = ko.computed(function () {
        if (self.demo()) self.myFunction();
    }, this);
}

var VM = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(VM);
```

Comment: Isn't there any other way without using subscribers?

Comment: @alvaro you can also use `customBindingHandlers` but thats for other day no need to over complicate things `subscribe` is the best way .

Comment: Thanks for it. I placed the subscriber inside the model to make it more simple.